# Separating Json array received from php - Android

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have a json function that gathers comments from a database. All the comments are gathered in a php array and sent back to the phone and turned into a jsonobject. Here is my json code

```
    JSONObject json2 = CollectComments.collectComments(usernameforcomments, offsetNumber);

return json2;
```

When it returns it the json looks like this

```
 {
"tag": "collectComments",
"success": 1,
"error": 0,
"numberOfComments": 16,
"offsetNumber": 1,
"comment": [
    "test 16",
    "test 15",
    "test 14",
    "test 13",
    "test 12",
    "test 11",
    "test 10",
    "test 9",
    "test 8",
    "test 7",
    "test 6",
    "test 5",
    "test 4",
    "test 3",
    "test 2",
    "test 1"
]
}
```

How can I separate all the comments and place them inside their own textview? The comment variable is classified as a string in the beginning of the Activity like this,

```
    private static String KEY_COMMENT = "comment";
```

Should this be set to array? If so then how can I put each comment into their own textView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use need to use getJSONArray("comment"); on the object.

You can then loop through each of the array items.

```
JSONObject test = new JSONObject("...");
JSONArray array = test.getJSONArray(KEY_COMMENT);
for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    textView[i].setText(array.getString(i));
}
```

Comment: To add to the answer.`{` represents a json object node.

`[` represents a json array node. was about to answer.

Comment: I did as you said and it only works for one comment. The variable KEY_COMMENT is classified as a String, does this need to be changed to an array?

Comment: @user2517036 no you can simple use `test.getJSONArray(KEY_COMMENT)` or `test.getJSONArray("comment")`.